# Stop python loop (List)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Im new to python. I have a loop

```
#todaystr gives string of sysdate e.g. 202307

if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder, todaystr )):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, todaystr ))

for f in  os.listdir(folder):
 
    if not ( f.startswith(todaystr) and f.endswith("hl7")) :
        
        break


    for g in os.listdir(folder)[:4] :
        if g.endswith('.hl7') and g.startswith (todaystr)    :
            shutil.move(os.path.join(folder, g),destination)
```

list data:

```
'202307',
'20230713-0955.hl7',
'20230713-0955.hl7', 
'20230713-0955.hl7', 
'20230713-0955.hl7', 
'20230713-0955.hl7',
'202307XY'
```

The loop should stop as soon as the list contains no data starting with "202307" and ending with "hl7". The Problem is that there is a folder "202307" so he stops instantly.

Thank you
Sorry for my bad english.

Im sure i have a Problem inside my if clause

Comment: Why sleep? Why call os.listdir twice? Don't shadow *list*. What do you hope to achieve with *tuple(list)*? Where is ende defined? True on its own doesn't really do anything. os.listdir() returns all directory contents - including other directories which may not be what you want.

Comment: Instead of doing it in that way you could first look which files have `.hl7`extension (`file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)`) and maybe save in an other list just the ones that do have the file extension you want

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
import os

folder = "/path/to/folder"
for f in os.listdir(folder):
    print(f)
    if not (f.startswith("202307") and f.endswith("hl7")):
        break
```

Comment: The problem now is that it stops because of the folder "202307". because the folder does not end on "hl7".

Comment: that's precisely what you asked for @goodvibes315

Comment: "The loop should stop as soon as the list contains no data starting with "202307" and ending with "hl7"."

Comment: or did you want something else?

Comment: @Mark what I see is that you have the same problem as he has. Because he says that his problem is that it stops when it reaches the fole with the name 202307 and so does yourse. So his question is wrongly asked, what do you realy need goodvibes315 ?

Comment: @Linux  Thanks, i solved it now with :   if  not any((item.startswith(todaystr) and  item.endswith(end) )  for item in list)  :
  break

Answer (score 0):

You can use the glob function to get all the files that match the pattern, and then determine whether there is a value.

It can be imported from the `glob` module, or using the `glob` method of the `pathlib.Path` class.

```py
import os

folder = "/path/to/folder"
print(glob.glob("202307*hl7", root_dir=folder))

"""
import pathlib

print(list(pathlib.Path(folder).glob("202307*hl7")))
"""
```